# Extracting substrings from CSV table

Tags: python

I'm trying to clean up the data from a csv table that looks like this:

```
KATY PERRY@katyperry
1,084,149,282,038,820
Justin Bieber@justinbieber
10,527,300,631,674,900,000
Barack Obama@BarackObama
9,959,243,562,511,110,000
```

I want to extract just the "@" handles, such as:

```
@katyperry
@justinbieber
@BarackObama
```

This is the code I've put togheter, but all it does is repeat the second line of the table over and over:

```
import csv
import re
with open('C:\\Users\\TK\\Steemit\\Scripts\\twitter.csv', 'rt',  encoding='UTF-8') as inp:
    read = csv.reader(inp)
    for row in read:
        for i in row:
            if i.isalpha():
                stringafterword = re.split('\\@\\',row)[-1]
        print(stringafterword)
```

Comment: The code doesn't do what you described - it crashes with a `NameError`.

Comment: I edited so it's formated just like I ran it here. It works like I described. I get multiple entries of the second line ("1,864,833,022,054,360").

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use `re`, you can get a list of strings in one line:

```
import re

#content string added to make it a working example
content = """KATY PERRY@katyperry
1,084,149,282,038,820
Justin Bieber@justinbieber
10,527,300,631,674,900,000
Barack Obama@BarackObama
9,959,243,562,511,110,000"""

#solution using 're':
m = re.findall('@.*', content)
print(m)

#option without 're' but using string.find() based on your loop:
for row in content.split():
    pos_of_at = row.find('@')
    if pos_of_at > -1: #-1 indicates "substring not found"
        print(row[pos_of_at:])
```

You should of course replace the `content`string with the file content.

Comment: Another `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: @rawing: `read`was the variable name used by the OP. I made it a working example...

Comment: Show the code with the OP version. It helps the OP to incorparate the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the "@" symbol is a symbol. Therefore the `if i.isalpha():` will return False as it is NOT a alpha character. Your re.split() won't even be called.

Try this:

```
import csv
import re
with open('C:\\Users\\input.csv', 'rt',  encoding='UTF-8') as inp:
    read = csv.reader(inp)
    for row in read:
        for i in row:
            stringafterword = re.findall('@.*',i)
        print(stringafterword)
```

Here I have removed the if-condition and changed the re.split() index to 1 as that is the section you want.

Hope it works.

Comment: New error: "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object". I guess it's progress!

Comment: I think this works as this uses re.findall(). Kinda forgot about this method.

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes it was meant to be searching through the counter 'i' not 'row'. Tested this just now.

Comment: Thanks @Suraj Kothari. This is the closest I got. It is returning an empty line after every handle instead of just the handle. Is there any way to remove these empty lines?

Comment: `for i in row` iterates through all characters in the row string - this is not what you want... If you want to stick to loops, use the second part of my code above.